# how to use distinct on multiple columns

Tags: database, oracle11g, distinct, analytic-functions

I have 6 fields

```
f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6
```

only fields 4 to 6 only vary i want result as single row based on field 1

Eg

```
name ,  age,    policy_no,  proposer_code,      entry_date ,        status
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
aaa     18        100002       101              20-06-2016              A
aaa     18        100002       101              21-06-2016              B  
aaa     18        100002       101              22-06-2016              c   
aaa     18        100002       101              24-06-2016              H
aaa     18        100002       101              26-06-2016              p
```

---

I want the last row alone only based on proposer code because that is the most recent entry date.

Comment: What  you want is interesting to know. What have you tried? You tagged it with analytic-functions, so at least you know what tool to use (or was the automatic tag chooser smart enough to pick it for you?)

Comment: Am waiting for someone who can now use Dense_rank and produce the same result. Coz i already provide using rank and someone repeated the same using row_number:-))))

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you just want to use `row_number()` like this:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by entry_date desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

In oracle you can use the below SQL query to achieve the resultset.

```
select name ,  
       age,    
       policy_no,  
       proposer_code,      
       entry_date ,        
       status
 from (
select name ,  
       age,    
       policy_no,  
       proposer_code,      
       entry_date ,        
       status,
       rank()over(partition by name ,age,policy_no, proposer_code order by entry_date  desc) rnk
from test
group by name ,  age,    policy_no,  proposer_code ,entry_date , status ) a
where a.rnk = 1;
```